# Create pivot/wide table using postgresql return error

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table

I have a table that look like this

| rank | country | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | 2020 |
| 2 | Austria | 2020 |
| 3 | China | 2022 |
| 1 | France | 2021 |
| 2 | Canada | 2021 |
| 3 | USA | 2021 |

I want to make it into a wide table with the result as follows

| rank | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | France |
| 2 | Austria | Canada |
| 3 | China | USA |

I tried to use CROSSTAB function from various resources on the internet with the code as follows:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB (
'SELECT rank, country, year
FROM country_yearly') AS ct(rank int, 2020 varchar, 2021 varchar);
```

It doesn't work and gives me this message

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2020"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In crosstab, you need to user order by , and give the year column in double quotes

For filtering the year i used generate series.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB (
'SELECT rank,  year,country
FROM conyear order by 1,2' ,'SELECT g FROM generate_series(2020,2021) g') 
  AS ct(rank int, "2020" varchar, "2021" varchar);

CREATE TABLE conyear 
(
    rank    int,
    country     varchar(300),
    year    int
);

INSERT INTO conyear (rank ,country ,year) VALUES ('1', 'USA', '2020');
INSERT INTO conyear (rank ,country ,year) VALUES ('2', 'Austria', '2020');
INSERT INTO conyear (rank ,country ,year) VALUES ('3', 'China', '2022');
INSERT INTO conyear (rank ,country ,year) VALUES ('1', 'France', '2021');
INSERT INTO conyear (rank ,country ,year) VALUES ('2', 'Canada', '2021');
INSERT INTO conyear (rank ,country ,year) VALUES ('3', 'USA', '2021');
```

The output ,(in you output you posted  china is not present in the year 2020)

```
rank    2020    2021
1   USA     France
2   Austria     Canada
3   null    USA
```